# Implementing hitbox polygon

Tags: xna, c#

I'm creating a shooter, it's still very early, but i'm implementing some polygon hitboxes.

So far i have created a polygon class, and i'm looking into how i can hook it onto my player.

I'm trying to stay away from having a `Tick()` function in my polygon class, and I would rather not update the position every tick (it would clutter up my tick functions). At the same time I would really like to have the positions in there somehow (it has a drawing function, and i will be using it for hit detection)

How would i go about implementing this polygon object into my entities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a good place to use [Composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition).

Give the `Entity` your `Polygon` class as a property and update it whenever the entity moves.

```
public class Entity {
    public Polygon Hitbox { get; private set; }

    public void Move() {
        // stuff to move player
        this.Hitbox.X = this.Position.X;
        this.Hitbox.Width = ...
    }
}
```

Comment: ofcourse! i just need to add a move method to my player! that would solve my problem of it cluttering my tick method, thanks!